# Opensource (or paid with trial) MM7 test Server?

Tags: testing, mm7

Does anyone know of a MM7 server I can use for testing my MMS client?

I've looked at mm7.net, but this is more of a toolkit than a testserver. And it is really lacking in good documentation (a how to guide etc).

thanks

Comment: I once evaluated InteLab's MM7.NET, but it looked "half-baked", with less-than-average support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answers... I actually ended up using my own baked PHP script, which just returns some MM7 Soap which is enough to test my stuff against.

The next step was testing it against test servers from ISP's. And now it is used against actual servers. So it can be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

ok.... I searched for mm7 mmsc and found this: [mbuni](http://www.mbuni.org/)

looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

[Now SMS/MMS Gateway](http://www.nowsms.com/downloads/) has MM7 features. It costs (and it's not cheap), but maybe it's good enough for evaluation. I think that they had trial versions before, I'm not sure what's their policy now. Check them out...